# Full and faithful functors

Tags: category-theory, definition, functors

Reading here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_and_faithful_functors, I found that a functor $$F:{\mathcal C}\rightarrow {\mathcal D}$$ is faithful if the function

$$F_{X,Y}\colon\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,Y)\rightarrow\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal D}(F(X),F(Y))$$

is injective for every $X$ and $Y$.

What is this function?

I suppose that it is

$$F_{X,Y}(f)(x) = Ff(x)\ \ \ \ \ \ \forall\ x\in F(X)$$

Comment: Yes, it's that function. Note though that in general you cannot write $x\in F(X)$ as $F(X)$ does not need to be a set. There are categories with objects that are not sets. So it's simply $F_{X,Y}(f)=F(f)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Note however that you need to assume that your categories are ``locally small'', so that indeed $\hom_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ and $\hom_{\mathcal{D}}(FX,FY)$ form actual sets.